# Django, why media images' urls don't work in production?

Tags: django, django-urls, production, pythonanywhere, django-uploads

I am working on a blog that needs to set in production, the problem comes when I set it production. All the static files load perefectly but the images I upload. I have tried with images previously uploaded before setting it in production, also after.
[Screenshot of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT9uk.png)

settings.py

```py
DEBUG = False

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'core.apps.CoreConfig',
    'unities.apps.UnitiesConfig',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS=(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE='whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Media files

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# CKEditor Settings

CKEDITOR_ALLOW_NONIMAGE_FILES = False
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'ckeditor_uploads/'
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
    path('<slug:unity_slug>/', include('unities.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT
```

*I'm using pythonanywhere*

Comment: I have imported static in urls.py

Comment: Have you looked in the web server access log to see the actual url being requested for the images?  And if so, is it the correct url?

Comment: I didn't thought that, I'll check it

Comment: Let's say the images are uploaded to media/uploaded_images directory. and the image name is test_image.png, the URL that you should see in the src attribute of img tag must be /media/uploaded_images/test_image.png . Check the src attr of <img> tag. what source are you providing? image.name or image.url ?

Comment: Maybe it's just a copy-paste error but you've got missing paren in urlpatterns for STATIC_URL. Btw. did you look at [PythonAnywhere help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingStaticFiles/) for debugging static files?

Comment: Yes, the url for the img is correctly generate. Also, I have tried to access directly to the image with the complete url ( https://<page>.com/media/uploaded_images/test_image.png) but still without working

Comment: Also, I have the STATIC_URL defined

Comment: Have you set up your static file mappings so that the PythonAnywhere static files system knows where to serve your static files from?  https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles

Answer (score 0):

have you import your static in top of **urls.py** ? I use django3.0

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

and for down side of **urls.py** I would code like this

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

for the **settings.py**  I only code like this

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

Comment: Yes, I have imported static in urls.py

Comment: I've checkit and i have it the same way